# Cómo guardar en la ruta de una imagen y subir la img a una ruta

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para creación de cuentas, en el cual pido foto de la cédula y quiero que el usuario suba la foto y se guarde la ruta en la base de datos.

se envia desde form el cual va a una base datos mysqli ya logre enviar todos los datos solo me falta lo de la img q no se como es

Quisiera saber cómo guardar en la base de datos la ruta de la imagen y cómo subir la imagen a una ruta específica.

Estoy usando PHP y MySQLi

No sé lo que me falta:

```
<?php
 require 'conexion.php';
  
 $nombre  = $_POST['nombre'];
 $primerapellido  = $_POST['primerapellido'];
 $segundoapellido  = $_POST['segundoapellido'];
 $carnetid  = $_POST['carnetid'];
 $direccionparticular  = $_POST['direccionparticular'];
 $fotocarnetid  = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['fotocarnetid']['tmp_name']));

$insertar = "INSERT INTO fondo VALUES ('$nombre','$primerapellido','$segundoapellido','$carnetid','$direccionparticular','$fotocarnetid') ";

$query = mysqli_query($conectar, $insertar);

if($query){

   echo "<script> alert('aporte ingresado correctamente');
    location.href = 'creaciondecuenta.php';
   </script>";

}else{
    echo "<script> alert('incorrecto');
    location.href = 'creaciondecuenta.php';
    </script>";
}

?>
```

este es el front:

```
<form action="creaciondecuenta-validar.php"  method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Nombre</label>
                                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Introduzca su Nombre" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Primer Apellido</label>
                                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="primerapellido" placeholder="Introduzca su Primer Apellido" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Segundo Apellido</label>
                                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="segundoapellido" placeholder="Introduzca su Segundo Apellido" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Carnet ID</label>
                                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="carnetid" placeholder="Introduzca su Carnet ID" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Dirección Particular</label>
                                        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="direccionparticular" placeholder="Introduzca su Dirección Particular" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Foto del Carnet</label>
                                        <div class="custom-file">
                                            <input type="file" name="fotocarnetid" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" >Suba la foto del carnet de identidad</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="my-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-wide btn-primary text-uppercase">ENVIAR</button>
                                </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres al decir "cómo subir la imagen a una ruta específica."?

Comment: @FernandoTorres si subir a una carperta la img y guardar la ruta en la db para despues poder mostrarla en php

Answer (score 0):

**Guardar el archivo recibido de un form y obtener la ruta local para grabarla en la base de datos**

Desde un formulario básico que envía por POST

```
<form action="tu-script.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fotocarnetid">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

En tu script lo referenciás como:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['fotocarnetid'];
$nombreOriginal = basename($archivo['name']);
```

Antes de moverlo a una carpeta, hay un tema acá, que podría ya existir un archivo con ese nombre, con lo cual conviene crearle un nombre único. Por ejemplo agregándole un ID único:

```
$nuevaRuta = '/arch-subidos/' . uniqid() . '-' . $nombreOriginal;
```

Bien, en este momento el archivo está en una ubicación temporal, con el nombre que se obtiene de `$archivo['tmp_name']`, y hay que moverlo de donde está a una carpeta de tu servidor para que se mantenga. Se usa [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

```
if (move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $nuevaRuta)) {

    // Se movió bien.
    // ahora se puede grabar $nuevaRuta en la base de datos

} else {

    // Error. Archivo duplicado?

}
```

> Nota: para insertar en tu base de datos la `$nuevaRuta` y el resto de los valores, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/193460)